# JPQL query not returning expected results

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

The following JPQL query is not returning results.  How do I alter it so that it returns the results that are expected?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Description> findDescriptionsForConcept(Concept conc) {
    System.out.println("in JpaSnomedRepository(), conc.getConceptPk().getId() is: "+conc.getConceptPk().getId());;
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT descr FROM Description descr WHERE descr.concept =:cid");
    query.setParameter("cid", conc);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

**NOTE: The solution was to change the name of one of the joincolumns in the manytoone relationship in the description class.**  But I am marking one of the answers below as accepted because the person invested a lot of time trying to help me.

Comment: Could try to check what query is actually generated. If using Hibernate, you can set hibernate.show_sql=true. This should give you some hint.

Comment: Ok, last thing missing now is how exactly would you like the query to look like. Just write the MySql query yourself, test it on your db and post it. We could then figure out how to define JPA mappings and how to construct a correct JPQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing method a little bit, setting `id` as parameter, not the whole `Concept`.

This code assumes your `SnomedDescription` class has something like `private Concept concept`:

```
Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT descr FROM SnomedDescription descr WHERE descr.concept.conceptPk.id =:cid");
query.setParameter("cid", conc.getConceptPk().getId());
```

Also one more thing looks suspicious for me - `Concept` and `Description` are bound with one-to-many relation. Consider revising that, you may want to make `Concept` has only one `Description`.

Comment: I think we discussed that problem yesterday and you managed to reference `Concept`s field `conceptPk`. Try using the same solution here, as there is something wrong with the variable name and 99% that problem is the same as yesterday.

Comment: First comment to this post: you used field name **conceptPK**. Previous comment: you used field **conceptPk**. It's one letter difference, but it matters.

Comment: Let's continue here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52062/discussion-between-alexey-malev-and-codemed

Comment: @CodeMed Can you also post JPA query that generates the output?

Answer (score 2):

The query generated by hibernate is fine. Let's analyze this step by step.

- We have a **SnomedDescription** entity that has a complex key made of two
  columns: *id* and *effectiveTime*.
- The **SnomedDescription** entity has a `@ManyTwoOne` relationship with another entity named SnomedConcept.
- **SnomedConcept** has also a complex key. From your question we are not sure what columns is it made of, but from the `@ManyTwoOne` relationship definition we can assume that it is also *id* and *effectiveTime*. Which is weird actually, because that would mean `@OneToOne` relationship should be more suitable, like @Alex Malev suggested (or the mapping is defined incorrectly). Basically we can't have two SnomedDescriptions of same id and effectiveTime, so there will be at most one SnomedDescription assotiated with a single SnomedConcept at a time.
- Why is the generated query fine? Because

  DESCRIPTION.CONCEPT.CONCEPTPK.ID **=** DESCRIPTION.ID

  That's how the relationship is defined!
- If the JPQL was something like `"SELECT descr FROM SnomedDescription descr WHERE descr.concept = :concept"`, the generated query would have two constraints: *id* and *effectiveTime* and would match at most one row.
- If you still would like to utilise @ManyToOne relationship, I believe that just removing the second @JoinColumn - of name = "effectiveTime" - would do the trick.

Comment: You're welcome. So what's the SnomedConcept primary key then? Also in your screenshot the MySql query has only one constraint, the conceptid, so why are you surprised it returns more results than quering by two constraints - id and effectiveTime?